Oracle SQL developer - do not detect line breaks
I am using oracle sql developer . Whenever we run any table / view sql with blank lines in between, the sql developer ignores it and executes the query perfectly. The feature is good, problem is the query fails in actual deployment where sql plus is used.
So is there a way we can let SQL DEveloper throw error when there is line break in between ?
Sample :
"CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_test AS
    SELECT
        * 
-- blank line
from test"

The above query runs fine in sql developer , but fails in sql plus.
Version used :21.4.1.349.1822

SQL> set sqlblanklines on
SQL>
SQL> create or replace view v_dept as
  2  select *
  3
  4  from dept;

View created.

SQL> select * From v_dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>


Thanks. Ideally i wanted the sql developer to throw error when it encounters blank lines in any DDL statement
